# Can vaadin $v-background-color be changed programmatically?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

`$v-background-color` is very useful. Whenever I change it - it changes all my labels, buttons and other components to an appropriate color. 
So I need to create few dark and light themes for web site. 
Can `$v-background-color` be changed programmatically or be set different for different layouts?

I tried to:

```
.dark-sales-list{
    $v-background-color: hsl(210, 0%, 25%);
}
```

but it did nothing. So I tried like this:

```
.dark-sales-list{
    background-color: hsl(210, 0%, 25%);
}
```

but my `$v-background-color` is still defined as light and I can't see neither labels, nor buttons properly. I could define `$v-background-color` as dark, but then my `.light-sales-list` won't show labels and buttons properly.

Vaadin 8.3.0. Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change SASS variables from Java. SASS files are compiled build time, and variables are processed then.

So what you can do is to define multiple preset styles in your theme with different stylenames, and you can programmatically change the stylename of your component.

Comment: Can I somehow change $v-background-color from inside of my preset styles?

Comment: If you mean can you change the value run time, no. This is the main difference between SASS variables and CSS custom properties. See more here: https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/